# How to control Flutter Status Bar color while navigating to screens

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification

In my Flutter app, there are 3 pages, SplashScreen, HomePage, and Notification Page, and all for three pages I have used different status bar colors, my splashscreen's status bar color is white and the Homepage and Notification's status bar color is red. When I normally open my app it shows the splash screen with the white status bar and then moves to the Homepage with the red status bar, and when I click on the notification tray sometimes it shows me the right colors of the status bar of Notification page but some times it display white status bar color of Notification page, What may be causing this type of issue?

Answer (score 0):

Trigger this on each page init depending on your preference and while navigating back(Use willpopscope/dispose/ onPressBack etc).

```
 SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarBrightness: isDarkTheme ? Brightness.dark : Brightness.light,
        statusBarIconBrightness:
            isDarkTheme ? Brightness.light : Brightness.dark,
      ));
```

Comment: I have already triggered this but same.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple way to **automatically** change the style of status bar when navigating to different pages, by debugging `SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle` and viewing some code and comments. Just **add `AnnotatedRegion` to your pages** and **set property `value` to the style you want for status bar**, for example:

In `MainScreen`:

```dart
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnnotatedRegion(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light, // < any style you want >
      child: Scaffold(
        body: ...
      );
  }
}
```

In `MenuScreen`，set `value` to a difference style:

```dart
class MenuScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MenuScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnnotatedRegion(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark, // < another style you want >
      child: Scaffold(
        body: ...
      );
  }
}
```

So when you navigate from `MainScreen` to `MenuScreen`, status bar will automatically change (`light` -> `dark`), and the same applies when returning, without calling `SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle` manually.

This way is not only suitable for routing navigation, even. When I use [ZoomDrawer](https://github.com/medyas/flutter_zoom_drawer), use `MainScreen` as homepage and `MenuScreen` as drawer, the status bar can still automatically switch to the corresponding style when swiping to open or close the drawer.

By the way, the reason why `SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle` sometimes doesn't work seems to be automatic settings of some widgets, causing manual settings to be overwritten. I found `setSystemUIOverlayStyle` was called twice when I navigated to a new page, once my manual setting and once automatic settings from unknown widgets. I guess it's related to `Scaffold`, `Appbar`, etc. because even if you don't control the style of status bar manually, changing the style of `Appbar` still causes the change of status bar.

Hope this is helpful to you!